# Search bar is removed on unfinished Swipe Back

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have situation like this:

Controller A and B:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupSearchController()
}
 private func setupSearchController(){
    let searchResultController = SearchResultsTableViewController()
    searchResultController.delegate = self
    searchController = UISearchController.init(searchResultsController: searchResultController)
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    searchController.searchBar.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
}
```

Controller A is main screen controller with search bar. After clicking search button controller A pushes controller B that displays results for search phrase. When I try start Swipe Back and cancel, situation from GIF occurs. Search bar from controller B is removed completely and cannot be shown even when scroller.

Only workaround that I have found is to create SearchController and set in navigation item every time in viewDidAppear. That fixes problem showed in gif, but there is a little flash/visible resize instead which is annoying. Is there any other workaround for this?

[image]

Comment: I also experience exactly this bug. This should be reported to Apple as a bug and will hopefully be fixed in a future version of iOS. Just for reference: I see this bug in iOS 11.2.6

Comment: I reported this as a bug to Apple with the ID: 38539314. In case somebody wants to report this too, you can reference my bug ID.

Comment: I'm on 12.1.2 and I still have this issue! It's been 2 days trying to find a solution!!